# justInTimeInstall for a Messaging Extension app not working on mobile (iOS/Android) Teams client

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

Working on a Messaging Extension app for Teams that opens a Task Module in a Teams Meeting. This app is installed from the "Built for your org" section of the Teams store after being loaded into a Tenant by a Teams Admin. Any tenant user who has the app installed can select the messaging extension from the … menu in a Teams Meeting to initialize the Task Module.

Before initializing the Task Module, the app's bot must be added to the meeting chat so an "Add app" button is presented after selecting the messaging extension. This button sends through a payload with the `justInTimeInstall` value set to `true`. When a new Teams user who has never used the messaging extension before tries to tap on this Add app button on a mobile device, the button either does nothing and the user is returned to the chat (iOS) or an error page with a retry button is presented and the retry button keeps presenting the same error page (Android).

When examining a network trace of this button press, a 502 code is being returned with the following JSON:

```
{
    "errorCode": 1008,
    "message": "<BotError>Bot returned unsuccessful status code Forbidden",
    "standardizedError": {
        "errorCode": 1008,
        "errorSubCode": 1,
        "errorDescription": "<BotError>Bot returned unsuccessful status code Forbidden"
    }
}
```

This combined with some other logging makes it seem like the response isn't even getting to the app's server. This is only a problem on mobile for a Teams user who hasn't used this messaging extension app. If the same user adds the app to the meeting from desktop/web, then they can come back on mobile and the "add app" button will work in any meeting from that point forward.

Is this a known issue or is there something that I might be missing here that's preventing the app from being added for new users on mobile?

Comment: We tried to repro this scenario at our end. On adding the app in meeting chat when a new Teams user tries to click on 'Add app' on mobile device, the app gets added and functionality works fine. The bot starts responding in the thread.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT happy new year and thanks for the reply! I'll continue investigating this from my end by looking at some of Microsoft's provided sample apps and comparing it to the one I'm working on, but is there any other information about the app I'm working on that could assist you in trying to reproduce the issue on your end?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I'm able to reproduce the issue with a sample app from Microsoft. Specifically the one at this link: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/demo%20manifest/msgext-action-quickstart.zip. For a new Teams user, tapping the OK button on mobile after filling out the card that that app presents does nothing and sends back the same error code.

Comment: We earlier checked following this sample. https://github.com/Trinetra-MSFT/89.teams-just-in-time-installation Could you please try this once and let us know if you are facing same issue?